# Windows RDP: which options to remotely kill a process which prevents rdp connection

Tags: windows, rdp, remote-access

I have windows machine (running w7x64) executing since months a given job. I don't have any sort of physical access to it and I usually control things via RDP (remote desktop protocol).

Currently the machine is doing the usual job, although, probably by virtue of some memory leaking process, I cannot access to it via RDP. 
Specifically, when trying to connect it remains stuck in the process of "configuring remote session" (Login information are typed already).

Which options do I have to see which processes are running and to kill them? 
Can I do some sort of console connection?
or can I issue a force-reboot command?

any help appreciated

Comment: do we have access to ps-remoting or ability to externally send commands ?  If not can you call someone in that office (with physical access) to power cycle ?

Comment: @Knuckle-Dragger, the machine is not really in an office..it is really a remote thing. I am afraid that sending someone there is the only option.

Comment: Can you connect to the server via My Computer > Manage, right click "Computer Management (Local) and select Connect to another computer.   If it works, goto services and start/stop termservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few options that may vary depending the version of Windows you're using.  Since you didn't specify a version, I'll show a dos version and a Powershell version.  These both assume you have the requisite permissions to the computer.

1. cmd.exe (works with just about any version of Windows): 

   Tasklist /s YourComputer

   Note the PID of the process you want to kill

   Taskkill /s YourComputer /fi "pid eq ####"  (replace #### with your PID)

   Or to reboot, use this command:

   shutdown /r /c "Comment about shutdown" /m \YourComputerName /t 0
2. PowerShell (The computer you're rebooting must have Powershell installed): 

   Get-Process -computername YourComputer

   Stop-Process -computername YourComputer -name ProcessName

   Or to reboot, use this command:

   Restart-computer -computername YourComputerName -force

Comment: tried everthing. Common answer is "Couldn't connect to remote machine"..

Comment: If all that fails it seems the RPC service is down (or to busy to respond). In that case a physical reboot is the only thing... All remote access mechanisms in Windows rely on RPC. That is why I always recommend VNC or TemaViewer as a fallback mechanism (they do NOT need RPC).